# Laravel scheduler kernel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application that makes use of the scheduler. I define schedules in the kernel and some of these schedules are defined by settings in my settings table.

**Settings table**

```
id | code     | value
1  | signout  | 18:00
```

**Kernel**

```
$schedule->command('appname:signout')->dailyAt(\App\Setting::where('code','signout')->first()->value);
```

I get the following error when deploying my app.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `settings` where `code`
>   = signout limit 1)

I'm confused as I have yet to add my .env file which would contain my username and password but it appears as though when the deployment happens it tries to initialize the kernel.php file?

Comment: you need to setup your .env
then if errors still occurred

run `php artisan config:clear`